# Warning: Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed

Tags: reactjs

**hi everyone I have a react.js application which must make three different components according to the click on a link the first component is a registration form the second a login form and the last is a slide which must be s 'display by default.
my problem is that if I click on login it displays the form well but puts me in the console this warning: "Warning: Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed. If necessary , trigger nested updates in componentDidUpdate.

Check the render method of Header. "

if anyone can help me figure it out and how i can go about it thanks in advance.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Signup from './Signup';
import Login from './Login';
import Entry from './Entry';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

const Header = () => {
  const [action, setAction] = useState("");
  
  if (action === "register") {
    const element = <Signup/>;
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('main-root'));
  }
  if (action === "login") {
    const element = <Login/>;
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('main-root'));
  }
  if(action === "default"){
    const element = <Entry/>;
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('main-root'));
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <Navbar id="navigarion" bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Nav>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <Nav.Link href="#" onClick={() => setAction("register")}>Signup</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#" onClick={() => setAction("login")}>Login</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#" onClick={() => setAction("default")}>Logout</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `ReactDOM.render` only once, at the entry point, and then have its children components decide what to conditionally render by *returning* one or the other JSX components. Something along the lines of:

```
const App = () => {
  const [action, setAction] = useState("");
  const element = action === "register"
    ? <Signup/>
    : action === 'login'
      ? <Login/>
      : <Entry/>; // if `default` is the only other option
  return (
    <>
      {element}
      .. other JSX, other components
    </>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main-root'));
```

Comment: thank you for your fairly quick response, it helped me a lot.